# Pubnub callback presence is delayed

Tags: pubnub

I used my presence callback method to display users that join or leave my chat room, but this actions seem very much delayed after the user logs off or logs on. What's the cause, and how can i achieve a swift response.

Comment: I would recommend posting some code here so that people can assist you.

Comment: As @jezzipin suggests, please post your code, and we're happy to help you.

Comment: Example Usage of Presence - http://www.pubnub.com/console?channel=my_channel&pub=demo&sub=demo&origin=pubsub.pubnub.com - notice the "Presence" section.  Presence will illuminate when new events occur such as Join/Leave.  Typically Presence Events should be pretty quick.

Comment: Can you show a link to your Chat App?  We will help you detect the exact next steps to achieve your goal.

Comment: the app is not hosted yet. i'll get back to you in a jiffy. Am just trying to do extra tests on my own side to make sure that am not missing something.

Comment: Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  am having this issue behind the scenes.

Comment: This will happen with Firefox when on localhost. This should not happen on  Chrome or Safari.